# When should I use an LMHOST file?

Tags: windows, netbios

I'm doing research on the LMHOSTS file. Can anyone tell me when I would want to use the LMHOST file?

Comment: Pretty much never. A good follow up question is "why does Windows still have an lmhosts file?"

Comment: In 20+ years as an IT guy in Windows networks, I have never used the LMHOST file.  Even back in the Windows For Workgroups days.

Comment: It can (used to) be useful for overriding central name resolution and for troubleshooting, much as the hosts file can be used today. I was surprised to actually find this useful about two years back in a now uncommon setup, which I certainly wasn't anticipating.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you would run into the LMHOSTS file these days. It is (was) used for name to ip and name to service resolution in the days of `NetBIOS`.

`LMHOSTS` is in function similar to the `hosts` file but also, as said, can map services unlike the `hosts` file. The syntax differs  and is exemplified in the default `LMHOSTS` file.

Just as the `hosts` file was largely obsoleted by `DNS` for centralised reolution, `LMHOSTS` was obsoleted by the `WINS` client/server system for `NetBIOS`. Both files remain as arcane and on the rare occasion useful name resolution mechanisms.

An interesting tidbit is the order of name resolution in a system, given that there are several possible mechanisms - `hosts`, `dns`, `lmhosts`, `wins`. This order is decided by the so called `node type`, which can be set manually if neccessary.

As `NetBIOS` (unlike `DNS` which has seen a new dawn) has been deprecated by Microsoft this is hardly useful information to a sysadmin these days, so I won't do the legwork of providing reference links. The internet is full of information so google to your hearts content.

My personal little guess is that the `LMHOSTS` file will disappear at the same time `NetBIOS` is fully removed by Microsoft from the Windows system. As long as `NetBIOS` is still configurable (although deprecated), we may find `LMHOSTS` lingering around.